# Creating access CommandBar with timer event using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have Office 2003.
I would like to create Commandbar with timer in MS Access using VBA.

What I want is on ever half a second command bar button gets the name of active forms and lists name of forms.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CommandBar using a Macro object in Excel 2003.  However, needing to update it every 1/2 second is complete overkill.  Forms won't get added or dropped very frequently, so you should have a static list for both performance and maintenance reasons.

The best way is to actually make a custom menu (an `AddMenu` line in the `Autoexec` macro) that calls a different macro with all the menu entries in it.  Actual command bars require a good amount of VB to make them work properly.